# Iphone : UITableView Header row repeating after 6 rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I am developing a Universal app. In this app there is a UITableView. Problem is that the header row in TableView is repeating after 6 rows in iphone and 9 rows in iPad.

I googled but not find solution to solve this header issue. please help.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [tripList count];
}
```

UiTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UILabel *lblTripNumber = nil;
    UILabel *lblTripState = nil;
    UIImageView *imgTripState = nil;
    UILabel *lblStateTitleText = nil;
    UILabel *lblTripNUmberTitleValue = nil;

    static NSUInteger const kTripNumberLabelTag = 2;
    static NSUInteger const kTripStateLabelTag = 3;
    static NSUInteger const kTripImageTag = 4;


    BOOL isiPhone = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            if (!isiPhone) // 1=Ipad        
            {
                lblStateTitleText = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205, 27, 250, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblStateTitleText.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32];
            }
            else
            {
                lblStateTitleText = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 130, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblStateTitleText.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            }
            lblStateTitleText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            lblStateTitleText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblStateTitleText.tag = 11;     
            lblStateTitleText.text = @"Trip State"; 
            lblStateTitleText.textColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblStateTitleText];

            if (!isiPhone) // 1=Ipad        
            {
                lblTripNUmberTitleValue = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(445, 27, 290, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblTripNUmberTitleValue.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32];
            }
            else
            {
                lblTripNUmberTitleValue = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 10, 250, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblTripNUmberTitleValue.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            }
            lblTripNUmberTitleValue.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            lblTripNUmberTitleValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblTripNUmberTitleValue.tag = 12;       
            lblTripNUmberTitleValue.text = @"Confirmation#";    
            lblTripNUmberTitleValue.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTripNUmberTitleValue];  

        }

    }
    else 
    {   
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            CGFloat xIndex = 6.0;       
            CGFloat xIpadIndex = 6.0;

            CGFloat TripNumberLabelWidth = 130.0;

            if (!isiPhone) // 1=Ipad        
            {
                imgTripState = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xIndex, 18, 50, 64)] autorelease];
            }
            else
            {
                imgTripState = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xIndex, 8, 32, 32)] autorelease];
            }

            imgTripState.tag = kTripImageTag;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgTripState];

            xIndex +=73;
            xIpadIndex +=85;

            if (!isiPhone) // 1=Ipad        
            {
                lblTripState = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xIpadIndex, 25, TripNumberLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblTripState.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:38];
            }
            else
            {
                lblTripState = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xIndex, 1, TripNumberLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblTripState.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
            }
            lblTripState.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            lblTripState.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblTripState.tag = kTripStateLabelTag;      
            lblTripState.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255) green:(241.0/255) blue:(216.0/255) alpha:1.0f];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTripState];

            xIndex +=132;
            xIpadIndex +=120;

            if (!isiPhone) // 1=Ipad
            {
                lblTripNumber = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xIpadIndex, 25, TripNumberLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblTripNumber.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35];
            }
            else
            {
                lblTripNumber = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xIndex, 0, TripNumberLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
                lblTripNumber.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
            }

            lblTripNumber.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            lblTripNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblTripNumber.tag = kTripNumberLabelTag;        
            lblTripNumber.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTripNumber];

        }else
        {
            // A reusable cell was available, so we just need to get a reference to the subviews using their tags.
            lblTripNumber = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kTripNumberLabelTag];
            lblTripState = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kTripStateLabelTag];
        //  imgTripState = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kTripImageTag];
        }

        lblTripNumber.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        lblTripState.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;


        int indCount = indexPath.row -1;
        TripDetails *trip = [tripList objectAtIndex:indCount];
        lblTripNumber.text = trip.tripNumber;
        lblTripState.text = trip.tripState;


    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: put code of viewForHeader in section and number of section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that , I removed

```
if (cell == nil)
```

and it worked fine. Actually it was looking for its tags in first header row and could not replace its values, so was creating problem.

Comment: I do the same, but it crashes my app

Answer (score 1):

You probably have only 6 items in your TableData.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   return [TableData count];

}
```

In your case 'TableData' is 'tripList'.

Answer (score 0):

check your viewFor header in section. if you are using array for your header views, then this array object is not properly allocated memory. it uses last object for all it's occurance and replace the old. Make a memory allocated object of array before you add objects to it. tell me if this is the solution

Comment: Yeah exactly, and since you are reusing the cells they will show you old cells that were already populated. That is why i said you should limit the number of cells to exactly the number of object you have in your array and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to reuse the cells, but the way you coded that is wrong. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446793/uitableviewcell-cell-identifier-memory-management/10446902#10446902) for the appropriate pattern. In a nut shell, you should only define shared cell attributes in `if (cell == nil)` section, the row specific attributes, like label text etc. should be defined outside of this section. This is not the case for your row at index 0.